# Why do my Web Part properties not show up?

Tags: web-part, 2013, branding

I've been developing a custom master page and page layout for SharePoint 2013, using the Design Manager. I've built the html pages and allowed SharePoint to translate them into .master and .aspx pages.

When I edit a page, and edit a web part on that page, the web part properties do not appear.

Is there some ContentPlaceHolder I need to expose, or something? Looking at other non-branded pages where it works, it looks like the Web Part Properties go inside the page somehow instead of being tacked on the side like in 2010.

Any explanation is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the process of using the Design Manager, but I did run into this when doing a regular .master.

I had to wrap my PlaceHolderMain ContentPlaceHolder in an AjaxDelta. My code ended up looking like:

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" 
                      BlockElement="true" 
                      IsMainContent="true" 
                      runat="server">
     <a id="mainContent" name="mainContent" tabindex="-1"></a>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Hope that helps or at least gets you started...

Comment: That did it! Not in a very clean way... but that made it show up. Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since Sharepoint converted your pages to .master, I believe there would be no problem.

Just a thought : 
Try looking into your css stuff. Where you might have added `"overflow:hidden"`, `"float"` for any of the parent container.

Comment: Well I've at least discovered that it's off the page somewhere, as if it's under an `overflow: hidden`, but i havent added any that it could be in... what i did to make it show up was to give it'd td a `position: absolute` and `left: 0`